# User-friendly dynamically formatted numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, numeral.js

I'm trying to format numbers dynamically when user enters or changes an input string field. I'm using React and a library NumeralJS for number formatting. 
I also use react-jsonSchema-form and I override theirs' number field.
I am stuck with the non-user-friendly way of moving the cursor either at the end or in the begging of the input value depending on if I change the thousands or the numbers after the decimal separator. 
 Is there any proper solution for that?

For example (adding a number in the integer part the cursor is moved to the end of the number):
[image]
[image]

ANSWER: 
I found a nice library for ReactJS which made the user interface friendly and it takes like 1 min to implement. I recommend it.
https://github.com/s-yadav/react-number-format

Comment: Can we have a fiddle or whatever showing your actual code ?

Comment: A thought: you need to have to variables one with the actual numerical value (what was typed in) and the other with formatted number as a string which you show to a user. You always update the numerical variable and parse it as a formatted string. To keep a cursor you can you javascript to remember previous position of a cursor and detect if it movers left, right or stays and then adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, @MaciejCaputa! The principle of how it works is the same as you described. I will have in mind the cursor settings for moving as you suggested.